# .NET Main Menu Help

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a main menu which accepts user input and then checks inputted password for validity against passwords I hardcoded into an array.
Firstly, in the for loop, only the first password index is being checked. I'd like the inputted password to be checked against EACH password inside the ValidPasswords() array.

Second, My for loop isn't doing what I want it to do. I'd like to give the user 3 chances to enter a password... If he/she exceeds 3, it tells them they've tried 3 times and exits the form. Right now, it just loops 3 times and exits without giving the user a chance to try again. If I put a return statement in, it just keeps returning and doesn't loop 3 times.

```
Public Class frmMain
    Dim ValidPasswords() = {"1234", "2222", "8918", "9911"}
    'Dim ValidPWList As New List(Of String)
    Dim pwIndex As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' For pwIndex = 0 To ValidPasswords.Length 'TOTAL PASSWORDS
    If txtPW.Text = ValidPasswords(pwIndex) Then


    Else
        For i = 0 To 2 '3 MAX ALLOWABLE ATTEMPT
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password, Please try again.", "Invalid Credentials")
            txtPW.Focus()
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Exceeded 3 password attempts.")
        Me.Close()
    End If


    If txtFNAME.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your name!", "Error")
        'ElseIf txtPW.Text <> "1234" And txtPW.Text <> "2332" And txtPW.Text <> "0192" And txtPW.Text <> "2010" Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password, Please try again.", "Invalid Credentials")
    Else
        g_welcomeMessage = ("Welcome, " + txtFNAME.Text + " " + txtLNAME.Text + ", to Image Viewer 1.0")
        frmImage.ShowDialog()
    End If


End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Thanks for trying me out!", "Goodbye")
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You got things back to front there Daniel.  I'll not bore you with advice on hardcoded passwords in your application and assume you're just trying to grasp the basics... I'll also assume .Net 4 because you haven't specified ;-)

I'm doing this by hand so excuse any minor syntax issues:

```
Public Class frmMain    
    Private validPasswords As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {"1234", "2222", "8918", "9911"}    
    Private failedAttempts As Integer = 0    

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
    If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtFNAME.Text) Then 
        MsgBox("Please enter a name") 
        Return
    End If

    If ValidPasswords.Any(Function(x) String.Equals(txtPW.Text, x)) Then
        ' User has a name and entered a valid password...
        g_welcomeMessage = ("Welcome, " + txtFNAME.Text + " " + txtLNAME.Text + ", to Image Viewer 1.0")
        frmImage.ShowDialog()
    Else
        failedAttempts += 1
        If failedAttempts = 3 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Exceeded 3 password attempts.")
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

' The other method here...
```

End Class

Comment: Yeah I suppose I did have it backwards. I was playing around with a bunch of different ways to write it... but this is awesome. Hopefully one day I'll be able to code like that :)  What I'd like to do is NOT hardcode the passwords... rather users register, save the created passwords to a database/resizeable array, and then use that. Probably too advanced though. Any direction? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely @Daniel - and I'm glad you're seeking out the knowledge instead of sticking to what you know - the best way to learn in my opinion.  Just google for VB.Net User Logon, there a loads of examples of different ways to do it. I believe you can even use Asp.Net's Membership provider quite easily from within an application. Just don't go for a full board system while your learning... built it up in stages - store user details in the app as you have - next a database - next a full blown custom made membership provider. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmmm, as an after thought, if you like the style of how I code, add to your ever growing list of things to read up and learn: Lambda Expression Tutorial (_note that multiline Lambda was introduced with .Net 4!_) and also Linq (specifically Linq to Entity / Linq to Object - the term varies based on how old the articles are). Happy coding

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the tips!